# Android custom listview vertical bar integration in an existing listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to integrate a vertical colored bar in front of my custom listview. I cannot succeed and I hope anyone could help me out.

The correct way without the colored bar:
[image: Correct way]

The XML code of the above image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/relation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/default_green"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketDepartmentName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticketDueDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/color_transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priority"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/status"
                android:background="@drawable/default_button"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/salesdesk_button"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

A nice try can be found here but does not work properly:
[image: My go]

Answer (score 0):

You could always add an imageview with an image of a vertical bar with the desired color inside another root LinearLayout which would be horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/colorBar"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#478848" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/relation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ticketDepartmentName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text3"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ticketDueDate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:text="Text4"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/priority"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#F89407"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="priority"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/status"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#478948"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="status"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```